# This FragmentManager should be recycled after use with #recylce()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, recycle

This is my code:

```
protected void showNewsItem(News news) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyNewsFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

and the error `This FragmentManager should be recycled after use with #recylce()` appears on the `beginTransaction` line.

I've tried adding `fm.recycle();` like the error suggests, but that gives me an error that `recycle` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)` version instead.
So in your case:

```
protected void showNewsItem(News news) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyNewsFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

Usually, the above idiom is sufficient for showing a `DialogFragment`.

The `show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String tag)` version is for "piggybacking" an existing `FragmentTransaction`.